# Getting syntax error in sudoers file I don't understand

Tags: sudo

I have an embedded system with the root mounted as read only.  I want to set up so my sudo users are able without a password change the setting (I plan to use the commands in the login and logout scripts for bash).

I am getting a syntax error on the line (see below) that defines a REMOUNT alias.  I can't figure out what that syntax error is.  Here is the snippet from the sudoers file

```
 # Cmnd alias specification
 REMOUNT = /bin/mount -o remount\,rw /,/bin/mount -o remount\,ro /
 # User privilege specification
 root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

 # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
 %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: REMOUNT
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the keyword `Cmnd_Alias` missing just before `REMOUNT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to state that it is a command alias:

```
Cmnd_Alias REMOUNT = /bin/mount -o remount\,rw /,/bin/mount -o remount\,ro /
```

Comment: Simultaneous posting as I figured out the answer for myself.  Just deleted my answer and ticked yours.

Comment: @akc42 apparently all three of us (including Nicola) figured it out at the same time. :D